# Is it not possible to use LDAP authentication in Pentaho BI Server v7 community edition?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

I'm checking if it is possible to setup LDAP in Pentaho BI Server Community edition. Upon checking there is a guide that instructs how to do this but for some reason the menus in the tutorial is different from what I'm seeing on my local server.

[image: tutorial screenshot]

[image: local screenshot]

Is there no option to go LDAP authentication on the community edition?

Comment: Pentaho tweak UI to not show LDAP configuration if LDAP have not being configured. Try configure LDAP manually )))

Comment: alright thanks for confirming that a workaround is possible

Comment: This is common approach for UI since some time ago. If you don't see on UI some functionality - most probably you have no plugin for that or just some 'manual' action or adjustment required for platform to detect you are start using this feature. This is attempt to keep UI clean, from my point of view - one of most contravention user experience decision. Personally I prefer to see this functionality exists but disabled for any reason instead of hide something if not used sub-floor.

Answer (score 0):

you can update below 3 files with LDAP server details,
present at below location (properties to update written in brackets)

../pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/

```
 security.properties 
 (provider=ldap)

 repository.spring.properties
 (singleTenantAdminDefaultUserName=username
 (singleTenantAdminUserName=unsename)

 applicationContext-security-ldap.properties
 (all ldap server, user and roles details update in this file)
```

you need to restart server and you are done

note: your local admin user will not work here as you are trying to authenticate with LDAP server

reference -https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.3/Setup/LDAP_security